# MySQL: Populating A Table with Random Dates or Null Vallues

Tags: mysql, random, null, create-table, auto-populate

I would like to populate a column in my table with either random dates from the past or Null Values. I would like to set the random dates between two dates, January 1 1920 and December 1 2018, or NULL VALUES.

I've come accross some confusing code that could be a solution for generating a random date during a specific period, but it doesn't cater for the null values.

```
INSERT INTO `FootballPlayers` VALUES (SELECT timestamp('2010-04-30') - INTERVAL FLOOR( RAND( ) * 366) DAY);
```

I would like for the column of the table to have something like.

```
+----------------+
|  Date of Death |
+----------------+
|   20/10/1990   |
|   01/11/1988   |
|   04/02/2006   |
|      NULL      |
|   17/05/2011   |
|   22/04/1972   |
|      NULL      |
|      NULL      |
|   13/04/1989   |
|   10/03/1999   |
+----------------+
```

Comment: Is `NULL` mandatory in the list of values?

Comment: Yes , there must be some NULL values, that is because this example the column shows the dates of deaths. Rows will have people still alive hence should have NULL values in those rows, if that makes sense. That's the part i'm struggling with. @ArunPalanisamy

Comment: I want to be NULL forever. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't get any null value by this query but if you use some case statement here then you can get this null here.
I used when-case statement and get exact result.
**Here you go :**

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN (SELECT FLOOR( RAND( ) * 366))  BETWEEN 50 AND 255 
THEN TIMESTAMP('2010-04-30') -INTERVAL FLOOR( RAND( ) * 366) DAY
ELSE NULL
END time_of_death
```

You can use this to your insert statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**ELT()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) function.

```
 SELECT ELT(N,MYRANDOMDATE) AS RANDOMDATE FROM 
        (SELECT TIMESTAMP('2010-04-30') - INTERVAL FLOOR( RAND( ) * 366) DAY AS MYRANDOMDATE, 
                FLOOR(RAND()*(2-1+1))+1  AS N) AS FINAL
```

Here i'm generating random number between 1 and 2 along with the random date. And I'm providing only one argument in `ELT()` function.When the random number is 2 , it will give you `NULL`. You can adjust this arguments based on your frequency of needed `NULL` values

[**Check demo here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9757176964b0b793460aea2592e82289)

Answer (score 0):

As a convenient single IF expression:

```sql
SELECT IF(RAND() > 0.2, TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 43200) MINUTE, NULL)
```